# How do you iterate through a list that returns "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I'm generating a bunch of lists in a project. On this particular one in the code I keep running into an error when trying to extract text from the list it's produces. In combination with BeautifulSoup, The code below produces a list of all titles from a YouTube page. It's in list format. I can print the list and see it. But when I try to iterate through this list and pick out text using the same list comprehension I've used before I get an error:

```
data = []
for label in soup.find_all('a'):
    data.append(label.get('aria-label'))
```

```
type(data) 
Out: list

print(data)
Out: [Python prints list]
```

But when going to iterate the list I get an error:

```
data_list = [title for title in data "Author Name" in title]

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

How can I iterate through this list without getting an error?

Comment: Can you check your line: `data_list = [...]` I get a syntax error on that line.

Comment: What data type does `soup.find_all('a')` return?

Comment: can you give us a sample of the list 'data' so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: your last snippet of python isn't even valid python

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if what you are returning when doing `label.get('aria-label')` is a non-null value.

```
data = []
for label in soup.find_all('a'):
    val = label.get('aria-label')
    if val is not None:
        data.append(val)
```